# Get full http request processing stack in Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, debugging

Hello I would like to dump full stack of processing http request (something like logs but with every method call listed from begin of http request processing to the end).
I need this to find where my multipart POST request with bigger files attached is processing different than that one with smaller files. If I had method stack I could simply compare them, because logs are insufficient and simply debug is horrible.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use profiler and do method/class call stack i.e JProfiler.